# Why onSaveInstanceState() is NOT needed in my situation?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle, onsaveinstancestate

being a beginner in Android, I learned that when we turn our phone, the activity is destroyed and recreated, hence the interest to save the values of the fields so as not to lose them during a rotation.

My "problem" is that, wanting to create a very simple activity with 3 edittext to save and restore them, even commenting on the code that manages backup and restore, the fields are not lost and I don't understand why.

You will find below the XML code of the layout of the activity + the source code of the activity.

**The layout of my activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nom"
        />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nomText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/prenom"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/prenomText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        android:hint="@string/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:onClick="toInputButton"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**The source code of my activity :**

```
package com.example.tp_preparation.landscape;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.tp_preparation.MenuOptionActivity;
import com.example.tp_preparation.R;
import com.example.tp_preparation.buttonInput.ButtonInput;
import com.example.tp_preparation.recycleView.DataModel;
import com.example.tp_preparation.recycleView.MyRecyclerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LandscapeActivity extends MenuOptionActivity {


    private EditText nom ;
    private EditText prenom;
    private EditText description;

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

        menu.findItem(R.id.landscape).setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landscape);

        nom = findViewById(R.id.nomText);
        prenom = findViewById(R.id.prenomText);
        description = findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);

        /*if(savedInstanceState != null){
            this.nom.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(String.valueOf(R.string.keyNom)));
            this.prenom.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(String.valueOf(R.string.keyNom)));
            this.description.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(String.valueOf(R.string.keyNom)));
        }*/
    }


   /* @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        savedInstanceState.putString(String.valueOf(R.string.keyNom), this.nom.getText().toString());
        savedInstanceState.putString(String.valueOf(R.string.keyPrenom), this.prenom.getText().toString());
        savedInstanceState.putString(String.valueOf(R.string.keyDescription), this.description.getText().toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }*/

    public void toInputButton(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ButtonInput.class);

        EditText nom = findViewById(R.id.nomText);
        EditText prenom = findViewById(R.id.prenomText);
        EditText description = findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);


        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putString(String.valueOf(R.string.keyNom), String.valueOf(nom.getText()));
        mBundle.putString(String.valueOf(R.string.keyPrenom), String.valueOf(prenom.getText()));
        mBundle.putString(String.valueOf(R.string.keyDescription), String.valueOf(description.getText()));

        intent.putExtras(mBundle);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**The parent class of my activity :**

```
package com.example.tp_preparation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.tp_preparation.landscape.LandscapeActivity;
import com.example.tp_preparation.recycleView.RecyclerViewActivity;

public class MenuOptionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_option, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.recycleView:
                Intent intenRecycle = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecyclerViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intenRecycle);
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.landscape:
                Intent intenLandscape = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LandscapeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intenLandscape);
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.inputPhysical:
                // do what you want here
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

**The activity before a rotation :**
[image: **The activity before a rotation :**]

**After a rotation (the code of onSaveInstanceState() is commented) :**
[image: After a rotation]

Comment: Thanks for the link, I close mine